# How to hibernate windows pc from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, shutdown, system-shutdown

How can I set my computer to hibernate after, say 18000 seconds?

This doesn't work:

```
shutdown -h -t 18000
```

Comment: Try running cmd like administrator

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming. I'd say it'd be more on-topic for SuperUser, but it has [already been asked there](http://superuser.com/questions/83437/hibernate-computer-from-command-line-on-windows-7).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the question: [Hibernate computer from command line on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/83437/hibernate-computer-from-command-line-on-windows-7), Phoshi's answer does it:

The hibernation time for cannot be set, unfortunately.

This works, though.

```
ping -n 20 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1 && shutdown /h /f
```

The ping is a hackish way of delaying the action. -n 20 should wait for 20 seconds.

(the double `&&` will allow you to do a ctrl+c to cancel the operation, if you use a simple `&` then `ctl+c` will make to automatically shutdown after pressing)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with that command for Windows is that you should use slashes instead of dashes. Dashes are used to add options in the Linux Terminal. Slashes are for adding options to Windows Command Prompt. Here's what you should use instead.

```
shutdown /h /t 18000
```

Comment: doesn't work in windows 11

Comment: Aw sad. Seems to be a trend with Win 11.

Comment: But this works: `timeout 1200 && shutdown /h`.

Comment: Oh, does the `timeout` command basically wait?